# What is causing the message "Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter"

Tags: android, southeast-asian-languages

I am new to Android and currently running some sample apps. From the logcat, I noticed the message "10-01 20:14:26.536: D/TextLayoutCache(15027): **Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter**" and wonder what could be causing this.

Is that an error of some sort?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I've noticed it happens on the S3 mini, but not other devices

Comment: it's happens on one plus one

Comment: I believe it's not an error. Probably your device supports Myanmar character converter, and the system prepares for it. If there's nothing bad happened, then I believe it's safe.

Answer (score -2):

I changed the language on the phone from UK English to American English and message the ceased.

Comment: My language is English (United States) but I still see it.

Comment: This doesn't help.. :( still I could see it